# Sorbet can't locate Gemfile

Tags: visual-studio-code, sorbet, ruby-lsp

Using VSCode with Ruby-LSP, I've been struggling to get it working. When Sorbet tries to start I get the following error.

```
Running Sorbet LSP with:
    bundle exec srb typecheck --lsp
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
[Error - 4:00:34 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
```

I've updated VSCode, I've uninstalled and reinstalled the extensions multiple times.

I'm using a Mac M1, but my project is running in a linux docker container and I'm using Docker dev containers with VSCode (but had the same issue when I was using vscode outside the container).

There's a gemfile in the `.ruby-lsp` folder, and my project has a gemfile.

Comment: Ruby LSP works independently from the Sorbet LSP. What makes you think this relates to Ruby LSP?

Comment: @AndyWaite Well they ship together with the Shopify Ruby extension and there's a Gemfile in the `.ruby-lsp` folder. So based on those facts my first instinct was that they might be connected in the issue I'm having. But then maybe they're not and now I'm left at square 1.